# Redirection Problems With Wordpress Sub Folder Installs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, subdirectory

Hi fellow overflowers,

I have a funny issue I have never seen before.
Currently we have a blog set up at domain.com.au/blog and a test domain for the blog set up at domain.com.au/blog/test

Both have wordpress installed.
Now when I go to the domain.com.au/blog the site works fine, can click any link and navigate through the website.

So here the problem lies, when I go to domain.com.au/blog/test the test site loads fine. But if I try to go to any other page in the test site "doamin.com.au/blog/test" I get redirected back to "domain.com.au/blog"

So I effectively can't navigate through the test site.
I think it's a redirection problem, as the domain.com.au/blog site has a plugin installed for redirection "Which is using like 300mb of database" yeesh.

Is it possible to have this set up of blog at domain.com.au/blog and test blog at domain.com.au/blog/test and has anyone else encountered this problem.

Cheers old mates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The wordpress server is running on iis, and there was a redirect wildcard character in the web.config which was picking up the word blog in doamin.com.au/blog and redirecting everything.